# Is there a way to have a separate class control a button on Main Activity class (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a class main activity (code show below) that controls the button on a screen of an app I am developing. I have a separate class named SQL which in theory would take the information inputted in the screen and pass it into a database. How would I make it so that the SQL class responds to the button being pressed in main activity and pass the info collected in Main Activity to the database via SQL Query. Would the class SQL need to extend Main Activity and have an onclicklistner?

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public Button mainScreen;
    public Button signIn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainScreen = findViewById(R.id.createAccountButtonMain);
        mainScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Create_Account.class );
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        signIn = findViewById(R.id.signInButton);
        signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    // Comment
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper) and use its helper methods from your MainActivity.

I will share a simple example below for you with using SQLiteOpenHelper. There are also other libraries to use database with less SQL queries. You can check them too. (such as [Room library](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).)

MainActivity.java - Note that here we are accessing the methods of the MyDbHelper.class to write or read from database.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        MyDbHelper.getInstance(this);

        EditText nameEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        EditText surnameEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextSurname);

        Button saveButton = findViewById(R.id.save_button);
        Button printButton = findViewById(R.id.button_print_db);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Person person = new Person(
                    nameEditText.getText().toString(),
                    surnameEditText.getText().toString());
            saveToDb(person);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Person saved: " + person, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            nameEditText.getText().clear();
            surnameEditText.getText().clear();
        });

        printButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            logPersonList();
        });

    }

    private void saveToDb(Person person) {
        MyDbHelper.getInstance(this).savePerson(person);
    }

    private void logPersonList(){
        for(Person person : MyDbHelper.getInstance(this).getPersonList()){
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, person.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the SQLiteOpenHelper class that manages our database.

```
public class MyDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = MyDbHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    private static MyDbHelper instance;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "my_database.db";

    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "person";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SURNAME = "surname";

    public static MyDbHelper getInstance(Context context){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new MyDbHelper(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private MyDbHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                COLUMN_NAME_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COLUMN_NAME_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_NAME_SURNAME + " TEXT);";
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onCreate(): " + sql);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(
                "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + ";");
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    void savePerson(Person person){
        try (SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase()) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_NAME_NAME, person.getName());
            values.put(COLUMN_NAME_SURNAME, person.getSurName());

            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    List<Person> getPersonList(){
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        try (SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase()) {
            Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME,
                    null, null, null,
                    null, null, null);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                personList.add(getPersonFromCursor(cursor));
            }
            cursor.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return personList;
    }

    private Person getPersonFromCursor(Cursor cursor){
        int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_NAME_ID);
        int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_NAME_NAME);
        int surNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_NAME_SURNAME);

        int id = cursor.getInt(idIndex);
        String name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
        String surName = cursor.getString(surNameIndex);

        return new Person(id, name, surName);
    }
}
```

And I created a POJO class to help pass the data.

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surName;

    public Person(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surName = surname;
    }

    public Person(int id, String name, String surName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surName = surName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurName() {
        return surName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surName='" + surName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```